# Does this algorithm correctly detect cycles in a directed graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph

I have a method to find cycles in a directed graph.

Given a directed graph G = (V, E), suppose there is a vertex w in G such that there exists a path from w to all other vertices in the graph. Consider the following method to find cycles in the graph. Run BFS on G using vertex w as the source. If we encounter another vertex twice, we claim that we have found a cycle. If we encounter each vertex only once, we claim that there exists no cycle in G.

The problem is: will I always get the right answer if I use this method?

Answer (score 0):

This will not always work. Consider this simple graph:

```
 A -> B
  \   |
   \  v
    > C
```

Here, there's a path from A to each node in the graph. However, during a BFS, you'll discover node C twice - once from A and once from B and will incorrectly report that a cycle exists.

Hope this helps!

Comment: So if it is a undirected graph, it will work, right?